# Fatal Signal 8 kept coming in android

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

When i was testing my game it works fine for some time but after sometime Fatal signal 8 error occurs and game stops.I tried to dig in that and found that it is floating point exception, but i am not doing any wrong mathematical calculation. I am making lot of objects is that could be cause ?

Comment: Probably you're dividing by 0.00000001 which is 0. If you have any divisions, then input a stuff /= (number < 0.0001) ? 1 : 0.0001; or it will eventually break

Comment: I have checked my code.I am not getting zero when diving operation.

Comment: Post the native stack trace from logcat

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if u also mention the SIGNAL Error shown just after the 8 digit.
If u are sure that it is not arithmetic error then it may also be stack memory overflow. Check if too many big arrays may be you have assigned, try to reduce them